# Create a type tuple from an array without "as const"

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript3.0

Is it possible to convert an array to a typed tuple with the type system alone eg. not required to use "as const"?

Example this is how one would create a typed tuple:

```
// has type = readonly [0, "string"]
const tuple = [0, "string"] as const;
```

Now from a non "as const" array is it possible to still create a typed tuple and preserve the order of the types?

Like this:

```
// has type = (number | string)[]
const array = [0, "string"];

// has type = readonly [0, "string"]
const tuple = array as ToTuple<typeof array> ;
```

Where ToTuple would be a type utility that converts the array into a typed tuple.

Comment: no, by the time you've gotten past `const array = [0, "string"]`, the type of `array` is already too wide.  The compiler has forgotten the order and length of that array.  The only way to capture that information is to tell the compiler to notice it when `array` is being defined, such as the `as const` assertion.