# Unwrapping an as const array into its mutable non-tuple counterpart

Tags: typescript

I have an array with `as const`:

```
// just a simple mock class
class Child { _ = "" }

const child = new Child();

const schema = [[child], child] as const; // readonly [readonly [Child], Child];
```

This array represents a union of types, so here, it would represent an array of `Child` or another array of `Child` (one level deeper). In essence, I want to transform the type of `schema` into `(Child | Child[])[]`.

```
type T = UnwrapAsConstArray<readonly [readonly [Child], Child]> // => (child | Child[])[]
```

I'm struggling with the logic to make this transformation possible. [This here](https://tsplay.dev/WPZrJN) is my pitiful attempt which does not work that well as you can see at the bottom.

[A playground where you can try to make a solution, with some test cases and expected behavior.](https://tsplay.dev/wRR2Qw)

Please keep in mind that I would like the solution to be recursive and to work for any amount of nesting.

Similar question: [Create a type tuple from an array without "as const"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561624/create-a-type-tuple-from-an-array-without-as-const). I need the "opposite" which I know is possible.

Comment: Could you put the [mre] directly in the plaintext of the question also?  `Child` and `child` are not defined and we can't require that people navigate away from Stack Overflow to answer the question.

Comment: Note: you mean something more than just "mutable"; the tuple type `[string, number]` is mutable. (e.g., `const x: [string, number] = ["",0]; x[1]++;`)  You are asking for something like its "mutable non-tuple" counterpart, although I don't know if there's a better name for that.  Could you clarify in the title/question?

Comment: Sure, sorry jcalz, it's my first time asking and I seem to have forgotten the simple things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach here would look like:

```
type UnwrapAsConstArray<T> = 
  T extends readonly any[] ? UnwrapAsConstArray<T[number]>[] :
  { -readonly [K in keyof T]: UnwrapAsConstArray<T[K]> }
```

This is very similar to a plain `DeepMutable<T>` type of the form

```
type DeepMutable<T> = { -readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepMutable<T[K]> }
```

which will leave primitives unchanged, and recursively strip `readonly` from any  object types, leaving arrays as arrays and tuples as tuples.  The only difference is the check for `readonly any[]`, where we explicitly grab the union of its element types `T[number]`, perform `UnwrapAsConstArray` on *that*, and produce a regular array.

That passes all the tests in your example:

```
type UnwrappedSchema = UnwrapAsConstArray<typeof schema>;
//   ^? type UnwrappedSchema = ({ _: string; } | { _: string; }[])[]
// not written as `(Child | Child[])[]`, but structrually identical

type Test01 = Assert<Equals<
  UnwrappedSchema, (Child | Child[])[]>>; // okay

type Test02 = Assert<Equals<UnwrapAsConstArray<
  readonly [readonly [1], 2]>, (2 | 1[])[] // okay
>>;

type Test03 = Assert<Equals<UnwrapAsConstArray<
  readonly [1, readonly [2, 3], readonly [readonly [4, 5, 6]]]>, 
  (1 | (2 | 3)[] | (4 | 5 | 6)[][])[] // okay
>>;

type Test04 = Assert<Equals<UnwrapAsConstArray<
  readonly []>, never[] // okay
>>;

type Test05 = Assert<Equals<UnwrapAsConstArray<
  readonly [1]>, 1[] // okay
>>;
```

Note well that this will recursively strip read-onliness from any object types like `Child` you put in there, and it doesn't know when to stop.  Anything that doesn't survive a type mapping will be weird (function types will become just `{}`).  If you need to adjust for those cases, you'll have to add logic to do so.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWBLEATaBvaB9aBeaARAdAL4CwAUJcAPYB2EALtMEqntHQKYDucbKABQBKANyVKAeknQAtPOgBbMAGsu0AKp0eAJzAAHAIIRY9JoZ16AntAhhGiCADMbYECGiN46xlyYQJCloGZghWLmUOAG0o1mQUAF0AGhYBBOhIFjNGcQppaALoAD0AfkDJACoKymgK6B0uMBR6EBsow3TcAD5oQyiEmrr2zp6+gYpa3v68Uf7B+sbmulapkdX5hqaWtsMUgCE1wUNoAB9oPeE5iaHd88Pjs4uryaPT88v7t6fxyc2lldejw+M2ggPezzqADpoYNJJRGFZ9OotLoDMZTCELNYADwAFR6+Fx0C4AA9fHQUDA-tsMnQrNMSpptHojCZsliwFY8VE6ABXRQAIy4OgSXWmAC4aoVMLJqcs2gBpaCIOjQNRWGhOaC4hLipmo1kY8yWTnchWi0iBBFI-UspEoADK4Ui+BRLPR7JNXOtXE1tmdYC6uXyBVK5Rk8lktrRbMxXts8BovPYdgczlc7k8fkYASoFB92uzAAYAIwcYwQYWMbEAUQAjry3BBsW6DPand5lClBAh4m9e6h+h8ukGrYj1LjiwAmctQKu1htNlvMmNGxgcrlylZRLdtEvJaBT0XdmdnEtD-oj3Lw8eFphFgDMs8rOmr9cbIGbrcNnpxu+gUQlik-5RFOKQPgeIEgQALCkACsKQAGwJChXTdmWZyCKe0APsCmHQW8cFvIhHwXqKo55gWk73gR+AVvO75Lt+Hpxn+iw0peKTcAAbsKl4UTeNrUYwRZEXRc6vguH5fiuP6saaIH7mh0DnuR155BGCi+EwKoAOa2IwvJOE4Y42vRkmwMSZJcBSMCMDovJcAScC5AWjGftitx7M5gh4l0IggkSpLkpSvTQIy9mOdAepOE2XDCFZIUwH5AXdNqiU2aFezhZ4DnqDFcU5ZF+XQLFn5cKIQA)